# Symfony OrderBy annotation with FIELDs

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, annotations

I have the following problem. I have 2 entities that are in a ManyToMany relation and I would like to sort them for a certain key word sequence.

Team.php

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Domain\Entity\Player")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="match_substitute_player_home")
     */
    public $substitutePlayersHome;
```

and now iam tring these to order it

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Domain\Entity\Player")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="match_substitute_player_home")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"FIELD(type, {'keep','def','atk'})"})
     */
    public $substitutePlayersHome;
```

My question is how to use the OrderBy Annotation right for a string value list.

It have to be some line like this, but this line dont work:

```
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"FIELD(type, {'keep','def','atk'})"})
```

sources of my tests:

-> http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html

-> [Propel ORM: Order By FIELD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036279/propel-orm-order-by-field)

-> https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIELD property is not defined by default in doctrine. Download and try this plugin. https://github.com/beberlei/doctrineextensions

Configure the package manually:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                field: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Field
```

Comment: but can i use this now as annotation? or have i write down my own repository statement?

Comment: I guess you can not use it. You can use it with DQL.